# Fetching data from angular directive using express interface

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have created an interface  using express and mongoose to fetch data from mongodb and to send it to client side.It s working fine when i fetch the data using wget on linux terminal  and on html browsers. But when I request the data using angular js $http method , it shows me the following errors.

```
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.         Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can anyone suggest me the error ofr how to get rid of this problem. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do an AJAX ($http.get) call from a different host/domain/IP. My guess is that you're running your Angular app on `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` and you're running Node on `http://127.0.0.1:9000`, which is a different Origin. There are two solutions:

1. Run them on the same hostname, for example both on localhost or both 127.0.0.1.
2. Add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header from Node, allowing your Angular host (origin) to access the back end via AJAX.

The reason for all this is a security measure, so that websites cannot just fetch any other website on the internet without explicit permission. Otherwise malicious websites could do an AJAX call to your PayPal or bank account for example.